# How to reset/clear checkboxes on clicking of label in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<div class="thickness-productlist">CLEAR</div>
  <span class="anchor3" @click="thicknessOnClick">Select (mm)</span>
              <ul class="items3">
                <div class="checkbox-alignment-application-filter">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="thickness-filter1"
                    class="vh-product"
                  />
                  <label class="productlist-specific" for="thickness-filter1"
                    >2.0mm</label
                  >
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-alignment-application-filter">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="thickness-filter2"
                    class="vh-product"
                  />
                  <label class="productlist-specific" for="thickness-filter2"
                    >22.0mm</label
                  >
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-alignment-application-filter">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="thickness-filter3"
                    class="vh-product"
                  />
                  <label class="productlist-specific" for="thickness-filter3"
                    >3.0mm</label
                  >
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-alignment-application-filter">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="thickness-filter4"
                    class="vh-product"
                  />
                  <label class="productlist-specific" for="thickness-filter4"
                    >4.0mm</label
                  >
                </div>
              </ul>
```

How to reset the checkboxes on click of clear, inside the dropdown i have checkboxes, So i want to reset the checkboxes on clicking of clear.

Thinking to solve using the toggle By setting the data value and in the method to toggle it. But not sure how to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question have been asked and solved before here on StackOverflow this is the link
[Uncheck CheckBox with its label in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629071/uncheck-checkbox-with-its-label-in-vuejs#49629314)